# pairwise comparison with Dunnett's adjustment in Stata

Tags: stata, adjustment

I am comparing the means of days between notification and diagnosis for 13 years, as I want to know if the mean days from 2013 is significantly different from the previous 12 years.

I was thinking of using pairwise comparison with Dunnett's adjustment, but this method assumes that 2001 is my control, and I was wondering if I can change the control to 2013?

I am currently using Stata 13.0 as my analytical software

Comment: Good that you answered your question, and quickly; nevertheless it was centred on the exact code to do what you want and as such was arguably off-topic here. Please see the Help Center for advice on software-related questions. Questions with code on which you want advice could go to Stack Overflow; questions on Stata could go to Statalist.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself, but thought I'd post it here if anyone else was wondering how to change the base

`fvset base last year`

for more info, look at `help fvset`

Please note I am using Stata 13.0

Comment: If that works for you,  good. Note that you can use factor-variable operators to establish alternative reference levels.  This is documented in the reference manual entry for `pwmean`.